# CM7 Launcherpro Changing Dock Icons

Tags: cyanogenmod, launcherpro

I downloaded some icons in extracted them to the SD card under a directory I made called icons. I've been trying to get launcherpro to change the dock icons, however whenever I click change icon the gallery always opens up. No matter what I do I cannot get the icons to show up in the gallery. I've tried deleting the gallery cache and deleting the gallery default actions as well as placing the icons in various different places on the SD card.

I would prefer the icons do not show up in the gallery at all so I could just use a file manager to choose the new icons. However, I cannot get the file manager open when I click change icon. The only program that will open is the gallery.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: After trying to fix the same issue, I just dealt with an icons folder showing up in the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you only have one "Image Chooser" app installed, and you would need to install another.  I know [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) registers itself as one, so if you install that maybe it will show up in the menu and then you can use it to browse to your icons.

Comment: Of course, this assumes CM doesn't force you to use the Gallery.